# Execute all the constructors of super class in multiple inheritance

Tags: typescript, oop

I am making a SDK where i am exposing one single class and extending multiple abstract classes (consider each class as a group that performs tasks for a particular component of the application)

For instance, i have two classes

```js
abstract class A {
   private name: string;
   private email: string

   constructor(name: string, email: string) {
      this.name = name;
      this.email = email;
   }

}

abstract class B {
   private email: string
   private password: string

   constructor(password: string, email: string) {
      this.password = password;
      this.email = email;
   }

}
```

Now i want to extend these classes into my third class `SDK`

```js
class SDK extends A, B {
   constructor(name: string, email: string, password: string) {
      // how can i call the constructors of both A and B separately?
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is "you can't".

A class can implement multiple interfaces, but it cannot extend multiple classes.  There are lots of ways to restructure your code to rely on two different classes, such as dependency injection.  You can also add behaviors to classes through [mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#how-does-a-mixin-work) (essentially higher-order classes).

Based on this

> consider each class as a group that performs tasks for a particular component of the application

It sounds like mixins might be the way to go?  But you should read up about OOP design patterns.

**Edit: Mixins**

Using mixins isn't a one-line change in your code.  Basically you are reworking `A` and `B` so that instead of being classes with their own constructors, they are snippets of functionality that you can apply to any class with a `name` and `email` property.  That allows us to apply both at once, since the classes that we are returning still fit that signature.

```
interface A {
  doA(): void;
}

interface B {
  doB(): void;
}

interface NameAndEmail {
  name: string;
  email: string
}

type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => NameAndEmail;

const addAFunctions = <TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) => {
  return class AClass extends Base implements A {
    doA(): void {
      /*...*/
    }
  }
}

const addBFunctions = <TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) => {
  return class BClass extends Base implements B {
    doB(): void {
      /*...*/
    }
  }
}

class BaseUser implements NameAndEmail {
  name: string;
  email: string

  constructor(name: string, email: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
  }
}

const SDK = addAFunctions(addBFunctions(BaseUser));

const mySdk = new SDK("John Smith", "johnsmith@gmail.com");

mySdk.doA(); // can call A methods
mySdk.doB(); // can call B methods
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzkAmA9qgBQCUAXMgG5HAEDcuAvrrqJLIigEKa58xXhWp0GzHGxwdw0eEmQA5OAFsIqEAQCiquMAA2AvMhBqI1AM5gooAOaT8EPYas37rdjjABPAA4oAMJEINZQAK4IYERQyAC8phAA7sikAHQZcFB2ltRwID4A2gC65PEAfMrmmjouBpK4CCHWyHAEBKgAYuEgUcDN8cgAPAAqvHCWKBAAHpBalsjBoTaR0VDlpOOT1GMTEGVxldgmUBBg4VAgyAgGEwuogbeWCzNzBAtbKMCqfgbOEOB7sZ8EISKJaPQCMCQfgAPQAKgyaXhsMEIOk%20Gk0kazTArXavG6vTA-VCg1Gn2QrwB70WuIiURiG0%20O0%20ByOaNO50u1yeH0edypsxpHz2yG%20v3%20gOQ-GOMOE4PEULlMOQCKRKLRmLRWK8N0FnwAqpNYhK-uppSp1DVdPojCqzOo3LYQA40c47c6PDITE1lgy1qRHRZkGF7AAaKl1L2usoq-BgAAWwEsaWDg2DjhBSZTaQ9hkG%20fqOs8Pr9LQAygARADSgzaHSJfWapAbhJ6zdCmz2xug5HIDRw5bxqh8FYIAGsM8lkNWa6QAEQAKSIiauFdUwCTC8jC4AVqvQpukwABOx1NJNVQLgdeUfjidpYhkAdq2HXfIfgxGdDqJNEd5cHvScnyIERX1hd8EE-aDvxlZA-0TADLCAA)

Comment: Hi I am new to typescript, any way to solve my problem with mixins please?